# How do I find the value of an unknown key in my HashMap and convert it into an int?

Tags: java

Doesnt really need much of an explanation, just wondering what would be the best and efficient way to do that. The HashMap has only one Key left, (checked with map.size() == 1), however the Key is unknown. The HashMap is `<Integer, Integer>`. 
Thanks a lot to everyone trying to help!

Comment: You can use Map#keySet() to obtain a set of keys. The rest should be self explanatory. You could also use Map#entrySet(), and iterate over these entries. An entry is an object that contains a key and a value. For example, `for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) { print(entry.getKey() + entry.getValue(); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `.keySet()` and `.entrySet()` returns `Set` you can't direct use a `get` operation like with `List`

1. Through `Stream` you can :

   ```
   int unknowKey = map.keySet().stream()
                               .findAny()
                               .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
   ```
2. Or, with `Iterator` :

   ```
   int unknowKey = map.keySet().iterator().next();
   ```

---

In term of efficiency, `iterator` is really superior:

```
Benchmark         Mode   Cnt    Score    Error   Units
MyBench.iterator  avgt     5   10,663  ± 0,175   ns/op
MyBench.stream    avgt     5   47,960  ± 4,819   ns/op
```

Comment: Nice analysis :) ... I think conversion to a stream takes time maybe

Answer (score 3):

Use the keySet method to get the key in a set and then iterate through the set to get the key, like so,

```
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    map.put(5, 1); // some map with only one key-value pair

    int a = map.keySet().iterator().next(); // obtain keyset, get iterator and get the next element (since you know map size is 1)

    System.out.println(a);
```